# Adding host specific *.c/*.h to autotool'ed project

Tags: c, linux, android-ndk, autotools

I'm attempting to cross compile a library using the Android NDK. I'm getting an error because the NDK's `linux/quota.h` doesn't implement `quotactl()` ([manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html)), as expected by the library.

Android kernels implement `quotactl()` as a system call, so my plan was to create a stub function that simply forwarded `quotactl()` to `syscall()` using `__NR_quotactl`:

```
quota.h:
#include <linux/quota.h>
int quotactl(int cmd, const char *special, int id, caddr_t addr);

quota.c:
#include "quota.h"
#include <sys/syscall.h>
int quotactl(int cmd, const char *special, int id, caddr_t addr) {
    syscall(__NR_quotactl, cmd, special, id, addr);
}
```

(omitted include-guards in `quota.h` for brevity)

The library I'm cross-compiling uses autoconf, libtools and automake. Because this is a host-specific change, I would like it to be transparent to the automake files, which would mean adding it to the `configure.ac` file.

I can add android specific autoconf code in a switch block already in `configure.ac`:

```
case $host_os in

   *mingw32*)
     ...
     ;;

  *darwin*)
    ...
    ;;

   *android*)
    have_android="yes"
    # something...
    ;;

esac
```

Is there an idiomatic, clean, autotool-ey way to add my `quota.c` to every build target and include my `quota.h` file only when the build is for an android host?  My goal is to keep this hack as independent from the rest of the project as possible.

I was planning to add a `compat/android/sys` directory in the root project directory and put them there. Then I could include it via gcc's `-I` flag and add `quota.c` to the list of sources for the components that require `quotactl()`.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but can you clarify: If the Android (Linux) kernel implements `quotactl`, you want special code to take advantage of it. If it's another OS, you just want a stub for `quotactl`?

Comment: Sort of. The Android kernels (there are at least 3 stock versions in the wild) definitely implements `quotactl()`, but the NDK doesn't provide a declaration. Other OS's are fine because the standard headers they use declare the function and something (presumably libc) implements it. My plan was, just for when the build is for an android host, to compile in my own implementation that calls `quotactl()` in the kernel using `syscall()`

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's redundant to define `ANDROID` macro. If you're using Android NDK, both gcc and clang already define `__ANDROID__` macro.

Second, the simplest way to achieve what you need would be to add quota.c to the common list of sources, but wrap its content with ifdef:

```c
#ifdef __ANDROID__

#include "quota.h"
#include <sys/syscall.h>
int quotactl(int cmd, const char *special, int id, caddr_t addr) {
    syscall(__NR_quotactl, cmd, special, id, addr);
}

#endif /* __ANDROID__ */
```

UPD: If you still want to use conditional set of sources instead of wrapping content with ifdefs, this is easy to do. Just follow [the doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Sources.html) and replace `linux` with `android`.

Comment: +1 for `__ANDROID__`. It seems like it would be cleaner to conditionally compile the whole source file rather than use `#ifdef`, I've updated the question.

Also, there isn't a common list of sources, is there an idomatic way to add it to all targets using autotools?

Comment: Well, if you still want use conditional set of sources instead of wrapping content with ifdefs, this is easy to do. Just follow doc: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Sources.html and replace `linux` with `android`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! If you want to add that to your answer I'll accept it